# How does tezos reward distributor tool calculate transaction fee for rewards?

Tags: baking, rewards, tezos-reward-distributor, payment

TRD is a common tool for tezos payouts. It's easy to get the overall amount of payouts from dry run. But in order to pay rewards, we also have to keep additional blockchain transaction fees in mind. Is there a quick way to estimate those costs knowing the overall amount of payouts that trd is going to pay out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRD always uses the minimum amount of transaction fee necessary when sending payments. The fee is calculated for each transaction based on storage, gas, etc (if those are involved).

Also, by default, TRD subtracts the transfer fee from the reward so there is 0 cost to the baker for sending transactions; nothing to keep in mind.